# LDAPConnection retrieve user by NT Account

Tags: c#

I am using the `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` library to query Active Directory. I have a use-case where I need to retrieve a user entry from the server starting with the user's NT account name (i.e.: NETBIOSDomainName\UserSamAccountName). This is the code I am using:

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(userDomain);
NTAccount userAccount = new NTAccount(userDomain, username);
sid = userAccount.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest
{
    Scope = SearchScope.Subtree,
    Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(objectsid={0}))", sid)
};

SearchOptionsControl searchOptions = new SearchOptionsControl(SearchOption.PhantomRoot);
searchRequest.Controls.Add(searchOptions);

SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(searchRequest);
```

The problem I have is that I do not know how to include the NetBIOSDomainName in the search. If I just search by the user's samAccountName I sometimes get multiple entries in the response because the same SAMAccountName exists in multiple domains.

Is there any way to avoid this hack that I am using?

Note that I have to use this particular library.

Comment: the userDomain strings in your above code should be limiting it to that domain. What are you using for those?

Comment: The userDomain limits the search scope to the current forest, not the domain. In my case, if the same group exists in 3 domains in the same forest, then I get 3 entries, one for each domain. I have the domain information expressed in the response entries' distinguished names, but trouble is that the NETBiosName and Distinguished Name Component do not always match.

Answer (score 1):

If you are querying ActiveDirectory, then use [DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145037(v=vs.110).aspx). Add reference to   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement dll and then you can use the example as shown below.

Directory services will allow you to easily set your Domain as part of look-up. Following example return [UserPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx) which can used to get all details on user account. Check [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx) for all available properties on `UserPrincipal`.

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public UserPrincipal FindUser(string username, string domain)
{
    var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);

    var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);

    // user will be null if not found
    // Remember to dispose UserPrincipal once done working with it.
    return user;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Unfortunately, the AccountManagement has other problems: specifically, group expansion for groups containing foreign SIDs causes the library to throw exceptions. Your code would certainly work, but I was really hoping there was a way to do it purely using this library. (They are in 2 different DLLs and I was hoping to eventually get rid of the second one altogether.)

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload of the SearchRequest constructor you can use - [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141885%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you need to set the first param to limit it to that domain

example

```
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest("DC=mydc,DC=com", sFilter, SearchScope.Subtree);
```

Comment: OK, but then question is how do I get "DC=mydc,DC=com" from the NETBiosName easily. If I could do that, I could just query the resulting entries' distinguished name for this string.